# Is there any way to call turtle screen from tkinter gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, turtle-graphics

I want to create gui for the game I have created. I'm encountering the problem when assigning class name to the button in tkinter. After script run, game runs and gui does not. Also I have noticed that is it enough just to import the game class to keep it happens. Appreciate for any advice.

#### Simplest gui

```
 from agario import game
        class menu():
            def __init__(self):
                tk.Tk.__init__(self)
                tk.Tk.geometry(self, '450x400')
                tk.Button(self, text='start', width=20, command=game()).pack()


        test = menu()
        test.mainloop()
```

#### Game class

```
    class game():
        s = 0.4                                 #### agario speed
        wn = t.Screen()
        wn.title("agario game")
        wn.setup(width=600, height=500)
        wn.tracer(0)
        wn.bgcolor("black")



        while True:

            wn.update()
            move(a.agario_object, wn, s).movement() ### movement part
            killing(k.killing_object, a.agario_object,k.killing_ball).agario_border_check(), killing(k.killing_object, a.agario_object,k.killing_ball).killing_ball_check() ## kiling balls part
            cko(a.agario_object,f.food_object, f.food).food_con(), cko(a.agario_object,f.food_object, f.food).boost_con(b.boost_object, b.boost) ## contacts part


        wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a well-defined way to call up a turtle screen from within a tkinter GUI.  But there's not enough code in your example, and you import libraries I don't have, so I can't provide a complete, custom example.

The `Turtle`, and `Screen` API is for *standalone* turtle.  When *embedded* inside a larger tkinter program, we use `RawTurtle` and optionally `TurtleScreen`.  At the tkinter level, you need to supply a `tkinter.Canvas`, or a `turtle.ScrolledCanvas`, instance:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()

canvas = turtle.ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
```

You can wrap that (scrolled) canvas in a `TurtleScreen` if you need to call screen-based methods:

```
screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-10, 100, 100, -10)
```

You then create `RawTurtle` instances using your canvas, scrolled canvas or screen:

```
turtle = turtle.RawTurtle(screen)
turtle.goto(90, 90)
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, I really apreciate it. Also I will check it out tomorrow and let you know about the result.